# Find a unit vector w that is perpendicular to v.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a unit vector w that is perpendicular to v. The vector v = (1, 1, ..., 1) in 9 dimensions

Solution: w = (1, −1, 0, . . . , 0)/√2 is a unit vector in the 8D hyperplane perpendicular to v.

My questions is why we say w is 8D vector?

Comment: Vectors orthogonal to $v$ form an eight dimensional space and $w$ belongs to it. But $w$ is a vector wit nine components.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the hyperplane is $8$ dimensional because it is perpendicular to a single vector which has dimension $1$. This is a consequence of the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) as $9-1=8$.